# TalkBack: System language is different from TTS language

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, accessibility, talk-back, samsung-galaxy-s-3-neo

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo with Android 4.4.2 (KitKat), and would like to use TalkBack.

Why are the system language and TTS language separate. What does this separation of tasks achieve? Anyways, I am trying to enable TalkBack. I tend to vary the system (user-interface) language between `English (US)` and `Italian`.

So, I'm stuck at the following message, which is preventing me from turning on and experimenting with TTS. Anyone know how I can handle this obstacle.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you select the same language under the following options:

```
 1. Settings ->  Accessibility -> Text-to-speech output -> ***** Text-to-speech, 
    settings button behind it -> Language -> English(United States)

 2. Language and Input -> Language -> English(United States)
```

You may select any Language, but choose the same language in both of these cases.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I understand. The system language is what is used to display the text associated with the various user interface elements (app icon names, menu item names, etc...) whereas the TTS language is what is used to sound these names out. If the TTS language were to differ from the system language, then you would hear all names pronounced incompetently (besides in the different accent), as the rules for sounding out words in different languages differ.